# How can we disable wp_generate_password function in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to disable random password generation in Word press ?

how can we disable wp_generate_password function

Comment: Why you want to disable this function

Comment: @deemi I want my users to choose their own password

Comment: WordPress never generate auto password .... it gives us option for own password

Comment: @deemi Yes it is generating. And I dont know how. Please help me

Comment: @deemi Random password is generated when clicked on password reset link ,not on register page

Comment: its mission impossible :) ... but i tried and search for it

Answer (score 6):

For inexperienced users can be annoying/confusing to see auto-generated password on first screen. Add the following code to the [wp-content/themes/your_current_theme/functions.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/) to disable this function.

```
add_filter( 'random_password', 'disable_random_password', 10, 2 );

function disable_random_password( $password ) {
    $action = isset( $_GET['action'] ) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
    if ( 'wp-login.php' === $GLOBALS['pagenow'] && ( 'rp' == $action  || 'resetpass' == $action ) ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $password;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to disable auto generated passwords.

1). follow the path
WooCommerce -> Settings -> Account & Privacy

2). remove checks in account creation section (shown in the picture)
[image: screenshot]

3). save changes.